# Can JNI handle any dll files (Windows)?

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am new to JNI. And have a few questions :
 Can JNI handle every type dll exists in windows? I wanted to link a library but it gives me error. Is it possible JNI and the dll are not compatible?

Excerpt from VB .NET (It works)

```
Private Declare Function ConnectReader Lib "rfidhid.dll" () As Integer
Private Declare Function DisconnectReader Lib "rfidhid.dll" () As Integer
Private Declare Function SetAntenna Lib "rfidhid.dll" (ByVal mode As Integer) As Integer
```

Full Code From Java

public class MainForm {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public native int ConnectReader();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    MainForm mf = new MainForm();

    System.out.println(mf.ConnectReader());
}

static {
  System.loadLibrary("rfidhid");
}
```

}

Error code shown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: MainForm.ConnectReader()I
at MainForm.ConnectReader(Native Method)
at MainForm.main(MainForm.java:13)
```

Can anyone point to me where I might do wrong?

EDIT:

Turn out I should be doing this (and it works)

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class HelloWorld {
   public interface MyLibrary extends Library {

        public int ConnectReader();     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Kernel32 lib = (MyLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("rfidhid", MyLibrary.class);
     System.out.println(lib.ConnectReader());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNI access uses mangled names; you will need to wrap the system API in a JNI stub with the correct name and arguments.  You can't call a system API directly.

I recommend researching JNI thoroughly, or using something like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) to alleviate some of the drudge work.

For example, given Java:

```
package com.mycompany.jni;

public MyClass
{
native boolean someMethod(String arg)
...
}
```

the native method linked is something like:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_jni_MyClass_someMethod(JNIEnv *jep, jobject thsObj, jstring arg)
```

Comment: You just saved whole day (for researching the wrong direction)

Comment: Glad I could help.  I still remember what it was like skinning my knees on JNI all those years ago.